# How can i install ubuntu 12.04.3-desktop.iso in a pendrive if the only option given after downloading it is by burning it into a CD?

Tags: 12.04

is there any other way to download it in the pendrive without burning it into a CD?? i've tried downloading it and it was not successful because it shows that i need to burn it into a F drive which is in a CD. but i wouldn't want that as i prefer putting it in the USB drive. please help

Answer (score 0):

Use Unetbootin to create a bootable USB. Next restart your computer with the pendrive attached. It should start by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question if there is another way to download it onto your pendrive instead of burning it to a CD then a proper answer is to use Unetbootin. Unetbootin will allow you to burn the iso file to a flash drive (AKA pendrive) so that you can use the flash drive to install Ubuntu. Unetbootin is available in Software Center.